# Sql injection regards

Tags: oracle, hibernate, sql-injection

I have a sql query like `create table tablename as "select * from table`.

I am using hibernate for creating these table. Here the `select * from ...` is not a static one. It will change dynamically..

sample code:

```
session.createSQLQuery("create table tablename as (select * from table)).executeUpdate();
```

`.setParameter()` does not work for the above case. Can anyone help me to solve this SQL injection exception?

Comment: What is the dynamic part? Where does it come from?

Comment: Tablename and the select statement will change dynamically.
for example 
1. create table table1 as select * from emp where empid = 1 

,2.create table table2 as select * from emp where empid = 3

Comment: I would be highly skeptical of this if these SQL statements are being generated by some user of your system.

Comment: these select statement are generated by java code, some kind of business logics there to generate  select statements

Comment: These tables that get created, are they then later dropped? If so, this is the wrong approach; instead, you should be creating a permanent Global Temporary Table (GTT). GTTs hold data at session level, meaning that although the table is always there, the data is temporary.

Comment: Yes these tables are dropped after some time intervals. GTT also never support in this, because the select statement(temporary tables) also not static(it may have different columns as well as row). why am using the tempory table is the select query  will take more time to get results. so am creating temp tables.. Is there any way to avoid sql injection for the above query.

i have tried below code to include as a paramater. but this doesn't support.

Comment: session.createSQLQuery("create table :tablename as :query")
.setParameter("query", "select col1,col2,col3 from table1 where ....")
.setParameter("tablename", "temptable")
.executeUpdate();

Comment: You can manage a White list of possible tablenames, or if you have some strong pattern how the tablenames are generated, you may check if this pattern applies.

Comment: The problem is solved. i have created a stored procudure to solve this.
Thanks all.